# print result of clustering with its users in sklearn

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I'm doing clustering for array (X) by KMedoids

```
X = np.array([0.85142858,0.85566274,0.85364912,0.81536489,0.84929932,0.85042336,0.84899714,
         0.82019115, 0.86112067,0.8312496 ])
X=X.reshape(-1, 1)

kmedoids = KMedoids(n_clusters=5, random_state=0).fit(X)
labels = kmedoids.predict(X)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(zip(kmedoids.labels_,X))
df1.index = df1.index
df1 = df1.rename({0: 'cluster', 1: 'parameter'}, axis=1)
df1['user'] = df1.index
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df1 = df1[['cluster', 'user',  'parameter']]
df1
cluster user parameters
0   3   0   [0.85142858]
1   4   1   [0.85566274]
2   4   2   [0.85364912]
3   2   3   [0.81536489]
4   1   4   [0.84929932]
5   0   5   [0.85042336]
6   1   6   [0.84899714]
7   2   7   [0.82019115]
8   4   8   [0.86112067]
9   2   9   [0.8312496]
```

and my question is how to print each cluster with ites users, I just need clustered rows looking that way

```
cluster 0
user 5
cluster 1
user4
user6
cluster 2
user 3
user 7
user 9
cluster 3
user 0
cluster 4
user 1
user 2
user 8
```

finally, Within each cluster sum up the distances for every user and then find for the one with the smallest value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by cluster number and then print each cluster's users.
You can then use the groupby method to group by users and use the sum method of the groupby object to achieve the sum of distances for each user.